# Lower bounds on eigenvalues of sum of two matrices (one of them is symmetric)

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis

Let $L$ be a matrix with eigenvalues($\lambda$ $\geq$ 0). If I add a constant value (say $a$) to all the elements of $L$, what can we say about the minimum eigenvalue of this perturbed matrix?
Note: $L$ has precisely one zero eigenvalues.

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\la\lambda\newcommand\1{\mathbf1}$There is no finite lower bound in terms of $a$ and the eigenvalues of $L$ on the minimum eigenvalue of the perturbed matrix $L+a\,\1\1^\top$ given only the information you gave; here, $\1\1^\top$ is the $2\times2$ matrix of $1$'s.

Indeed, let
$$L=\begin{bmatrix}\la&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
for some real $\la\ge0$ and $b$.
Then the eigenvalues of the perturbed matrix $L+a\,\1\1^\top=\begin{bmatrix}\la+a&b+a\\a&a\end{bmatrix}$ are
$$t_\pm:=\la/2+a\pm\sqrt{(\la/2+a)^2+(b-\la)a},$$
so that for any given real $\la\ge0$ and $a>0$ we have $t_-\to-\infty$ as $b\to\infty$.

Also, for any given real $\la\ge0$ and $a>0$, if $b$ is close enough to $-\infty$, then the eigenvalues $t_\pm$ are not real, and hence it makes no sense to even talk about the minimum eigenvalue of the perturbed matrix.

Comment: It's not $L+aI$, it's $L + a e^T e$ where $e = (1,\ldots,1)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael : Thank you for your comment. I don't know why I wrote that. :-) Now the notation is fixed.